# XNA- Texturing problem, exporting model

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

How,can I disable coloring when texture is applied, because right now
the texture is being colored over.

```
foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
{
    effect.TextureEnabled = textureApplied;

    if(textureApplied)
        effect.Texture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice,System.IO.File.OpenRead(texturePath));
    else
    {
        effect.DiffuseColor = ti.DiffuseColor;
        effect.EmissiveColor = ti.EmissiveColor;
    }
    ...
}
mesh.Draw();
```

Also, is there any easy way for xna to export models? Or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set the DiffuseColor and EmissiveColor to Color.White when `textureApplied` is true. And please cache the result of `Texture2D.FromStream` and don't call it every frame!